# Applying a complex formula on an entire row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of long strings separated by a comma that I'm splitting by a regex pattern using `REGEXREPLACE`. Then I'm using `TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!Q2,","))` in another sheet to split the text into separate phrases and transpose them into a column.

How can I apply this formula on the entire row so each column will follow the same logic?

Using the Fill Handle gives the following result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!Q2,",")) | =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!R2,",")) | =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!S2,",")) |

When the expected result is:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!Q2,",")) | =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!Q3,",")) | =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!Q4,",")) |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

`ARRAYFORMULA` does work nicely with `SPLIT`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Sheet1!Q2:Q4," ")))
```

Note that you can also use `Q2:Q` to read all the rows, but you need to have the same number of columns in your result sheet as the number of rows in the source sheet, else you will get `#REF`.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For more complex situations you can also try

```
=INDEX(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FILTER(Q2:Q,Q2:Q<>""),","))))
```

[image]